# VB.net DataGridView incorrect display when change data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I put the code below on ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged and the first time it's OK, but if I change the value of combo the DataGridView contain the new values with the olds :(

```
Adapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table where id_user = " & ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString & ";", cn)
Adapter.Fill(AppDataSet11.timbrature)
DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the `DataGridView` before you place new values:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your solution but return an error "You can not delete this list". After I realized that I had to clean the Dataset associated. Thank you again